# How to test for NaN with generics (or why NaN.Equals(NaN) == true)?

Tags: c#, iequatable

I need to find **min** and **max** values in an **array** (not taking into for possible **NaN** values in this array).

This would be easy only working with `double`, but these FindMin and FindMax functions have to work with generics types.

I have tried to test for *generic* NaNs in this way:

```
bool isNaN<T>(T value) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return !value.Equals(value);
}
```

but `Equals` is returning `true` for `double.NaN` ??!!

I have a workaround like this for now:

```
bool isNaN<T>(T value) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var d = value as double?;
    if (d.HasValue) { return double.IsNaN(d.Value); }

    return !value.Equals(value);
}
```

My question is more about understanding why first solution did not work, is this a bug ?

You can find small test code [here](https://gist.github.com/3449954)

Comment: Is that code really supposed to read `value.Equals(value)`? Or rather something like `value.Equals(... some other value ...)`?

Comment: var result = double.NaN.Equals(double.NaN); // result is true.

Comment: Why would you expect that testing a value is equal to itself to be false?

Comment: @PeterRitchie I'm guessing that in cases of "not NaN" the expectation is that value *will* equal itself (and thus return "not NaN"). The other expectation is that NaN will not equal another NaN meaning the `isNaN` behaves as intended (returns NaN). The expectations are the problem.

Comment: @CitizenInsane Generics in this instance are more pain than they are worth, simply utilise `float.IsNaN` or `double.IsNaN` when required.

Comment: @Adam and all, I know this is more pain, and just testing for  float/double is fine in practice. The effort is about having an elegant solution without knowledge about what type <T> is. Even if again I do expect other types than float/double to define for some sort of 'NaN' value in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but Equals is returning true for double.NaN

Yes. And it does regardless of generics:

```
double x = double.NaN;
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(x)); // True
Console.WriteLine(x == x); // False
```

Note that if the second line printed False, that would either make the [`IEquatable<T>.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) inconsistent with the `Equals(object)` override, *or* you'd have to make `Equals(object)` violate the reflexivity requirement of `object.Equals(object)`.

Basically this sort of thing is nasty whatever you do with it.

Given that you're trying to find max/min values, you might want to try using `IComparable<T>` instead of `IEquatable<T>` - that may well let you detect NaN in other ways. (I don't have time to check right now.)

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I truly meant by NaN.Equals(NaN) returns true. I already tried with IComparable but it was not conclusive. Anyway, your answer fully suit my needs and wonders, thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I would simply use `double.IsNaN` and let the compiler implicitly cast `float` members where required:

```
float myFloat = float.NaN; // or 0.0f / 0.0f;
double myDouble = double.NaN; // or 0.0 / 0.0;

Console.WriteLine(double.IsNaN(myFloat));
Console.WriteLine(double.IsNaN(myDouble));
```

"Wastes" a very small amount of memory on the stack and uses a cast op call, but hey ho it is generic *enough* to cater for any type that can hold a "numeric" NaN.

Alternatively, using `float.IsNaN` appears to work with rudimentary testing, but requires an explicit downcast of a `double` (downcasting `double.NaN` and `0.0 / 0.0` appears to work, as in, it reports `NaN` correctly).

<sub>You cannot generically constrain on a subset of value types with any cleanliness (or at all, I'm not 100% certain) so I wouldn't bother chasing the `<T>` route personally.</sub>

---

If you want a general solution that means the callee doesn't need to care what is passed in, you can do the following:

```
    static bool IsNaN(dynamic d)
    {
        float dub;

        try
        {
            dub = (float)d;
            return float.IsNaN(dub);
        }
        catch (RuntimeBinderException)
        {
        }

        return false;
    }
```

However, this incurs boxing. Note as well that `dynamic` is required and `object` will not work, so this also invokes the DLR (and also swallows all `RuntimeBinderException`s).

Comment: Even if heavy of course, I did not thought about dynamic. Nice approach. Thanks :)